# Hana studio - append sign commenting the code

Tags: sql, hana, hana-studio

I am using sap hana 1.0 sps12 and hana studio 2.3.8.

When i use double pipe '||' as sql append, studio is treating code after double pipe as comment.

E.g.

> select 'A'||'B' from dummy;

Hana is treating 'B' from dummy; part as comment.

Where can i change this setting

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour and have never come across it. Can you try to reproduce this with a vanilla eclipse workspace and default settings?

Comment: @lars if  you know where is this set in preferences , can you help?

Comment: I'm am not aware of such a setting. That's why I recommend trying with a vanilla profile.